# Computing PCA on GEE for a large area

Tags: google-earth-engine, pca

I have been trying to implement Forest canopy density approach by computing

- advanced vegetation index, bare soil index and Scaled shadow index
- perform pca for Advanced vegetation index and Bare soil index to yield Vegetation density as the first component.
- then computed the Forest canopy density using Vegetation density and scaled shadow index.

I am facing a challenge with the pca since i get computational time out especialy on computing centered covariance on GEE.

The code is here below please help on how efficient to do this on large areas:

```
// Combine  AVI and BSI to one image with two bands 
var AVI_BSI = AVI.addBands(BI)
// Map.addLayer(AVI_BSI, {}, 'AVI_BSI',0)


  //  function for mean 
var means_centered = function (Image) {
  var bandNames = Image.bandNames();
  
  // Mean center the data to enable a faster covariance reducer
  // and an SD stretch of the principal components.
  var meanDict = Image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: region,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 10e9
  });
  var means = ee.Image.constant(meanDict.values(bandNames));
  var centered = Image.subtract(means);
  
  return  [centered,bandNames]
}

// This helper function returns a list of new band names.
var getNewBandNames = function(prefix,bandNames) {
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length());
  return seq.map(function(b) {
    return ee.String(prefix).cat(ee.Number(b).int());
  });
};

// This function accepts mean centered imagery, a scale and
// a region in which to perform the analysis.  It returns the
// Principal Components (PC) in the region as a new image.
var getPrincipalComponents = function(centered, scale, region, bandNames) {
  // Collapse the bands of the image into a 1D array per pixel.
  var arrays = centered.toArray();

  // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
  var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    // crs:'EPSG:32737', // 
    bestEffort:true,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });

  // Get the 'array' covariance result and cast to an array.
  // This represents the band-to-band covariance within the region.
  var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

  // Perform an eigen analysis and slice apart the values and vectors.
  var eigens = covarArray.eigen();
 
  print(eigens,'eigen'); 
  // This is a P-length vector of Eigenvalues.
  var eigenValues = eigens.slice(1, 0, 1);
  print(eigenValues,'eigenvalues')
  // This is a PxP matrix with eigenvectors in rows.
  var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1, 1);

  // Convert the array image to 2D arrays for matrix computations.
  var arrayImage = arrays.toArray(1);

  // Left multiply the image array by the matrix of eigenvectors.
  var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors).matrixMultiply(arrayImage);

  // Turn the square roots of the Eigenvalues into a P-band image.
  var sdImage = ee.Image(eigenValues.sqrt())
    .arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('sd',bandNames)]);

  // Turn the PCs into a P-band image, normalized by SD.
  return principalComponents
    // Throw out an an unneeded dimension, [[]] -> [].
    .arrayProject([0])
    // Make the one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
    .arrayFlatten([getNewBandNames('pc', bandNames)])
    // Normalize the PCs by their SDs.
    .divide(sdImage);
};

// Means Centered for 
// var Means_cn = means_centered(AVI_BSI); 
// print(Means_cn[0])
// var VD = getPrincipalComponents(Means_cn[0], pca_scale, region, Means_cn[1]).rename(['VD1', 'VD2'])

// Map.addLayer(VD,{},'VD')

//scale VD datasets 
 
// var SVI = normalization_100(VD,region, scale)
var SSI = normalization_100(si,region, scale).rename('SSI')

// print(SSI)

// Compute FCD

var FCD = function(image, SSI) {
  return image.expression(
      '(VD*SSI+1-1)**0.5',
      {
        'VD': AVI_BSI.select('AVI'),
        'SSI': SSI.select('SSI')
      }).rename('FCD'+year);
};

var FCD_ = FCD(AVI_BSI, SSI)
```

Comment: Please use formatted text rather than pictures for any code and error messages that you present.

Comment: let me add link to the code  https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0d88e4bac9a255ff7f06f1cb3f68326 the PCA part does not go through i get computational time out

Comment: Links to code are OK as background to your question but please [edit] it to include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck as formatted text.

Comment: // Compute the covariance of the bands within the region.
    var covar = arrays.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.centeredCovariance(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: scale,
    // crs:'EPSG:32737', // 
    bestEffort:true,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });                                                                                                                                       i have tried to do PCA of advanced vegetation index and bare soil index, the above snnipet is part of the PCA function am implementing. the code fails due to computation timeout

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.